# WSO2 AM Profiles (API Manager 2.6.0)

Tags: wso2-api-manager

We are implementing a distributed architecture that uses two Gateway in a cluster with rsync (a manager node and a worker node).

According to this documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Product+Profiles#2ef3910138bf4c9dadd384fb4fec40c2) we can run the worker node using *-Dprofile=gateway-worker*.

We are wondering which profile to use to start the manager node. We have tried to use *-Dprofile=gateway-manager* but it doesn't work.

Should we start the Gateway manager without any profiles (default profile)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest versions of APIM, gateway-manager profile is removed. Instead you could use the publisher node for the gateway manager tasks. Previously Publisher node publishes to the worker node and from the rsync or nfs, worker nodes get the artifacts. With the new model, publisher publishes the api to itself (now `<ServerURL>` in the `< APIGateway>` section in the publisher node should be localhost) and worker nodes will have to sync with the publisher's deployment folder.

Comment: With your suggestion, how would multi-gateway deployments work with only a single NFS drive?

Comment: @MiddlewareManiac All the gateway node's /repository/deployment/server folder needs to be shared between gateway nodes. this path can be mounted using the NFS drive.

Comment: @MiddlewareManiac also refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Distributed+Deployment+of+the+Gateway